# Vue-Dropzone processQueue not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, dropzone.js

On my website you can upload a dog with attributes and images.
Vuejs is the frontend and Laravel the backend.
I am using this [vue-dropzone component](https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone) in my project to upload images.

---

**The problem**
 
I want to upload the images and the attributes of a dog at the same time (when the user clicks the submit button), so that the image files can be linked to the dog's id in the database.

---

**Laravel function to register a new dog** (*route: 'api/dogs'*)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $attributes = [
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'type' => $request->input('dogType'),
        ...
    ];

    $dogId = Dog::insertGetId($attributes);

    // Upload files
    if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
        // getting all files
        $files = $request->file('files');
        // Count files to be uploaded
        $file_count = count($files);
        // start count how many uploaded
        $uploadcount = 0;
        if($uploadcount == $file_count) {
            return true;
        } else {
            FileController::store($request, 0, 0, $dogId, $files, $uploadcount);
        }
    }
    return $dogId;
}
```

**Dropzone component** (*Formdropzone*)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <dropzone 
            :id="this.id" 
            :url="this.url"
            :accepted-file-types='"image/*"'
            :use-font-awesome="true"
            :preview-template="template"
            :auto-process-queue="false" <----
            :upload-multiple="true"
            :parallel-uploads=100
            :max-files=100
            @vdropzone-success="showSuccess"
            >
        </dropzone>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Dropzone from 'vue2-dropzone'

    export default {
        props: {
            id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            url: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },
        components: {
            Dropzone
        },
        methods: {
            showSuccess(file) {
                console.log('A file was successfully uploaded')
            },
            template() {

            return `
                <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
                    <div class="dz-image" style="width: 200px;height: 200px">
                    <img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>
                    <div class="dz-details">
                        <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size></span></div>
                        <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
                    <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
                    <div class="dz-success-mark"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                    <div class="dz-error-mark"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
                </div>
                `;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Register dog component**

```
<tab-content title="Images">
    <div class="form__input__wrapper">
        <span class="label">Images (optional)</span>
            <formdropzone url="http://domain.local/api/dogs" ref="dogDropzone" id="dogDropzone"></formdropzone>
    </div>
</tab-content>
<script>
    import Formdropzone from './Formdropzone'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {    
                dog:{
                    name: '',
                    dogType: '',
                    ...
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            publish() {
                this.$http.post('api/dogs', this.dog)
                   .then(response => {
                        this.$refs.dogDropzone.processQueue() <----   
                        this.$router.push('/feed')
                    })
            }
        },
        components: {
            'formdropzone': Formdropzone
        }
</script>
```

---

**The error message**

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'processQueue' of undefined

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: The error indicates that for some reason the ref doesn't exist. This could be for any number of reasons (publish is called before the component is rendered possibly) but there is not enough code here to determine why.

Comment: @Bert thank you so much for your comment! That already helps me a lot!

Comment: Because you are using an arrow function, scope shouldn't be an issue here.